# Display legend of grouped data (different colors) in chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, legend

I have a horizontal chart with different colors to group the data. In the code below, the chart layout displays as intended, but the legend shows only a single color (yellow). How can I force the chart to show the legend of the other two while still maintaining the layout of the chart? The legends should be "Group 1" for yellow, "Group 2" for orange, and "Group 3" for pink.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var dataArr = [21, 34, 21, 90, 88, 88, 22, 11, 10, 62, 55, 96, 62];
var dataLabelsArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"];
var dataColorsArr = ["yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "hotpink", "hotpink", "hotpink", "hotpink"];


var data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: dataLabelsArr,
    backgroundColor: dataColorsArr,
    data: dataArr
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dataLabelsArr,
    datasets: [{
      data: dataArr,
      backgroundColor: dataColorsArr,
      label: "Group 1"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="175"></canvas>
```

Comment: What are you trying to display? Your data is not grouped. Such a chart will look different if the data is grouped. Perhaps you need a different chart?

Comment: I am trying to display a horizontal bar chart like the one above, with different colors for three "groups" in the data (`A-D` as `Group 1`, `E-I` as `Group 2`, and `J-M` as `Group 3`) so that they are colored differently and have the 3 "groups" legends/colorboxes displayed. I did not group the data as I tried adding additional datasets but an orange bar is added beside each yellow bar. I do not know any solution on how to create the chart above but with the colorboxes/legend added.

Answer (score 0):

You only provide a single dataset so you will get only 1 legend item. This legend item uses the first backgroundColor it sees as it's colour for the legend.

To achieve what you want you need to use 3 different datasets, each with a single static backgroundColor.
Then you can either use object notation to match the points to the correct X label or you can pass X amount of null values to fill up the space

Comment: If you pass zero or null, then the bar width will be reduced, because they are grouped

Comment: Yeah you can increase the bar percentage to counter it

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on [LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234495/16593275)

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"];

const group1Data = [21, 34, 21, 90];
const group2Data = [88, 88, 22, 11, 10];
const group3Data = [62, 55, 96, 62];

const getResultData = (mainIndex, ...data) => data.reduce((acc, data, index) => {
  if (mainIndex === index) return acc.concat(data);
  return acc.concat(data.map(() => null));
}, []);

const groups = [
  {
    label: 'Group 1',
    data: getResultData(0, group1Data, group2Data, group3Data),
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    label: 'Group 2',
    data: getResultData(1, group1Data, group2Data, group3Data),
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  },
  {
    label: 'Group 3',
    data: getResultData(2, group1Data, group2Data, group3Data),
    backgroundColor: 'hotpink'
  }
];

const myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: groups.map((group) => ({
      ...group,
      barPercentage: groups.length
    }))
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="175"></canvas>
```